# Android NDK call java method form cpp

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I'm need to open Camera from NDK, i'm try to open some java methods from C++ file. And i haven't idea how to do this! I don't know how call java method from native activity or without creating Java Activity!

i have **Tester.class**

```
 import android.util.Log;

    public class Tester {

        static {
            System.loadLibrary("cocos2dcpp");
        }

        public void callFromCpp(){
            Log.i("DEBUGGER_TAG", "Something!");
        }



    }
```

**main.c**

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "CCEventType.h"
#include "platform/android/jni/JniHelper.h"
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#define  LOG_TAG    "SUPER_DEBUGGER"
#define  LOGD(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)

using namespace cocos2d;

void cocos_android_app_init (struct android_app* app) {
    LOGD("cocos_android_app_init");
    AppDelegate *pAppDelegate = new AppDelegate();
}
```

How i can open callFromCpp Method?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
{
        JavaVM* jvm;
        env->GetJavaVM(&jvm);
        // now you can store jvm somewhere

        // in the new thread:
        JNIEnv* myNewEnv;
        JavaVMAttachArgs args;
        args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6; // choose your JNI version
        args.name = NULL; // you might want to give the java thread a name
        args.group = NULL; // you might want to assign the java thread to a ThreadGroup
        jvm->AttachCurrentThread((void**)&myNewEnv, &args);
        // And now you can use myNewEnv

        jclass testClass = (*myNewEnv)->FindClass(myNewEnv,
                    "com/your/package/name/Test"); // get Class

        jmethodID constructor = (*myNewEnv)->GetMethodID(myNewEnv, cls, "<init>", "()V");

        jobject testObject = (*myNewEnv)->NewObject(myNewEnv,testClass,constructor);

        jmethodID callFromCpp = (*myNewEnv)->GetMethodID(myNewEnv,
                testClass, "callFromCpp", "()V"); //get methodid

        (*myNewEnv)->CallVoidMethod(myNewEnv,testObject,callFromCpp);

    }
```